# How to display Picker with one item using Playbook's QNX

Tags: actionscript, picker, qnx, blackberry-playbook

I've got a QNX Picker control that isn't displaying the selected values when there's only one item in the picker. For example:

```
import qnx.ui.picker.Picker;

var pick:Picker = new Picker();
var arr:Array = [{label: "hi!"}];
pick.dataProvider = new DataProvider([new DataProvider(arr)]);
pick.selectedIndices = [0];

addChild(pick);
```

The result is a blank picker. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. When there are 2 items in the arr Array, the picker actually shows the selected Indices.

How do I get the picker to display the selected item when there is only 1 item to choose from?

I'm using Burrito, with Playbook SDK 0.9.3.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are going to populate the picker at some point in order to actually use it, so you could just use your existing array and add a blank entry:
var arr:Array = [{label: "hi!"}, {label: ""}];
and then pop the array to remove the blank item before you add new data.

Comment: This lists 2 items, 1 with the data, one blank. I'd prefer not to give the user the option to pick the blank.